# I installed vue-ellipse-progress plugin and "document is not defined" error getting every time

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
 
  

 `import VueEllipseProgress from 'vue-ellipse-progress';
  export default {
   components: {
       VueEllipseProgress
       }
  }`
```

document is not defined error when everytime this is running
i also checked  to remove server side rendering and same also

Comment: Are you using vue cli? if so my guess is that globals are disabled, `app.config.globalProperties.window = window` and `app.config.globalProperties.document = document`

Comment: im new to vue and nuxt i dont realy know about cli

Comment: ok, This solution is what you are after since its NUXT. document and windows dont exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058544/document-is-not-defined-in-nuxt-js

Comment: i tried that :<client-only placeholder="loading...">
   <VueEllipseProgress
:progress="progress">
  
</VueEllipseProgress>
  </client-only>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an [example](https://github.com/setaman/vue-ellipse-progress/issues/108) how you can include `vue-ellipse-progress` globally to your project.

`plugins/vue-ellipse-progress.js` Create plugin.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueEllipseProgress from "vue-ellipse-progress";
Vue.use(VueEllipseProgress);
```

`nuxt.config.js` Include plugin in config.

```
plugins: [
    {
      src: '@/plugins/vue-ellipse-progress.js',
      mode: 'client'
    },
  ],
```

`your-component.vue` Use component.

```
<client-only>
     <vue-ellipse-progress :progress="50" />
</client-only>
```

The official guide for nuxt plugins https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: thanks the "document is not defined" error is gone but component progress bar is missing